# Initialize repositories protected by Spring authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I use Spring Boot Data REST to map Hibernate repositories of entities to REST routes. I also use Spring Security's `@PreAuthorize` annotation to secure certain methods of those repositories. This works fine during production, but when I want to programmatically initialize the repositories with data (e.g. adding a first user to get started and some other sample data), it complains that "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext". I realize that this is because there is no authenticated user in the security context at the time I configure the database (with an autowired component saving objects to repositories). However, I'd like to temporarily circumvent this authorization during configuration, so that I can initialize the database.

Is there any way to achieve this? And if not, how can I manually log in in the initialization method? I've seen some attempts to the second approach, but they all require access to an `AuthenticationManager`, which I don't know how to obtain.

Comment: Atleast one super user should be there. It should have all access. We can put entry while starting the server using some SQL scripts in resources location.

Comment: How you are adding initial data? Via REST? If so why REST and not something like liquebase?

Comment: I'm adding initial data through an @Component, with `repository.save` (so programmatically)

Comment: @Prasath I indeed am adding a super-user in this setup component. However, I'd prefer not to do it in SQL, but in Java code, if possible

Comment: We can do some workaround. Hardcode one user record and save while server start. Do this hardcode from service class with some method with @postconstruct.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, service class methods with @PostConstruct are not executed before Spring's Security service is up. I'm getting the same error when I try putting the initialization in such a method.

Comment: Something called in memory authentication. Try this. It may work for case.https://memorynotfound.com/spring-security-in-memory-authentication-example/

Comment: Thanks for the link! I had considered this, and it's something I may have to resort to in the end for testing purposes, but I would really like to be able to achieve this with persistent authentication... That would mean less modification for tests (so more realistic tests) and easier deployment later-on.

Comment: Is that works ?

Comment: To be honest, it's not what I was looking for. I appreciate the suggestion, but I really don't want to change the authentication method. I'd simply like to temporarily disable global method authorization while I'm adding entities and then turn it back on again...

Comment: __" adding a first user to get started and some other sample data "__ is that your main (only) goal?

Comment: My main goal is indeed to intialize the database with a user, and some other necessary bare-bones data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following codes to create a fake user who has enough permission and set it to the `SecurityContext` just before running that protected method:

```
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();

//Setup the permission that the user should have in order to run that method.
//It is the customized value based on your security configuration
grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN")); 

//Ensure this user is enabled , active and has above permission
User user = new User("admin", "password", true, true, true, true, grantedAuthorities);

Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

After executing that protected method , reset the `SecurityContext` (which is equivalent to logout) :

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution: Ignore security and focus on an empty repository

```
@Component
class InitializeDataIfNoDataPresent {
  private final UserRepo repository;

  public InitializeDataIfNoDataPresent(UserRepo repo) {
      this.repository = repo;
  }

  @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
  public void init() {
    if(0 == repository.count()) {
      setupData();
    } 
  }

  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
  public void setupData() {
    // your existing setup
  }

}
```

When the application starts and your repository is empty, `setupData()` will be called even if there is no user present.

ref: [stackoverflow-initialization-secured](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/stackoverflow-initialization-secured.git)